# Can I use the global queue in the python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I expect to put items into a global queue in a thread. Is it possible?

This is the pseudocode:

```
def parse_a_file():
    global sql_qool
    sql_qool.put(xxx)

sql_qool = Queue.Queue()

t = threading.Thread(target=parse_a_file)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

Comment: The class is `queue.Queue` and yes, it is possible. What would it have taken to try it before posting?

Comment: @Booboo It was `Queue.Queue` in Python 2.

Comment: @KlausD.Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update for Python 2**

```
import Queue
from time import sleep
import threading

def parse_a_file():
    # the following global is not really required
    #global sql_qool
    sql_qool.put('xxx')
    print 'I put xxx.'

sql_qool = Queue.Queue()

t = threading.Thread(target=parse_a_file)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
sleep(1) # give daemon thread a chance to run
```

Prints:

```
I put xxx.
```